# Remove hyphens and replace with spaces and capitalize in liquid

Tags: regex, shopify, liquid

Using liquid, I am using product tags to generate page titles. I want to the page titles to be free from hyphens and each word capitalized.

EXAMPLE:

If the tag (used to generate the title) is "potato-chips". I want the title to be "Potato Chips".

If I use:

```
{{current_tags.first}}
```

It generates a title of "potato-chips".

If I use:

```
{{current_tags.first | replace: '-', ' '}}
```

It generates a title of "potato chips".

If I use

```
{{current_tags.first | replace: '-', ' ' | capitalize}}
```

we get a title of "Potato chips".

If any one knows how I can get the title "Potato Chips", that would be great.

If it matters, some tags (used to generate the titles) are "word"; some are "word-word"; some are "word-word-word"; and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split the tag on '-' then loop over the words capitalising each one:

```
  {% assign words = current_tags.first | split: '-' %}
  {% for word in words %}{{ word | capitalize }} {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This worked perfectly. Do you know a way to keep all the words "and" lowercase? For instance, potatoes-and-chips would become Potatoes and Chips ? Cheers

Comment: @Ben Replace `{{ word | capitalize }} ` with `{% if word == 'and' %}{{ word }} {% else %}{{ word | capitalize }} {% endif %}`

Comment: @StephSharp Bravo! Worked perfectly. Many thanks, Steph.

Comment: and if you have this loop inside a `{% capture %}`, you can use the `| strip` filter on the result to drop the trailing space

Answer (score 1):

[According to the docs](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/output#camelize), the `camelize` (or `camelcase`) filter should work:

> **camelize**
>
> Converts text into CamelCase.
>
> **Input**
>
> {{ 'coming-soon' | camelcase }}
>
> **Ouptut**
>
> Coming Soon

But when I tested it, I found the filter doesn't seem to be adding the spaces like the doco says it should.

In this case, [BBG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21829139/1367622) is the workaround I would use (split on '-' and capitalize each word in the array).

Comment: Cheers. I had tried camelcase, but it wasn't feasible for the reason you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

If using CSS is an option, I'd just do that instead of dealing with the splitting and looping in Liquid.

```html
<span style="text-transform: capitalize">
  {{current_tags.first | replace: '-', ' '}}
</span>
```